# How to rewrite store view code in Nginx?

Tags: magento2, overrides, store-view, nginx

I have some trouble to fix this issue.

I have a Magento 2 installation with two websites and several store views:

https://www.websiteone.com/onenl
https://www.websiteone.com/oneen
https://www.websiteone.com/onede

https://www.websitetwo.com/twonl
https://www.websitetwo.com/twoen
https://www.websiteotwo.com/twode

Magento wants every store view code to be unique, so we've made them unique.

Now I want to rewrite them to shorter urls like:

https://www.websiteone.com/nl
https://www.websitetwo.com/nl

But I'm not able to get it working. I tried several things like:

```
location /onenl/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    rewrite ^onenl/(.*)?$ nl/$1 break; 
}
```

or

```
location /onenl {
    rewrite ^onenl nl last;
}
```

I or get a 404 CMS page not found from our base store view. Or I get an nginx 404 not found and in this situation I think he doesn't understand to fire up index.php.

What am I missing? :)

Thanks!

Comment: Please check with below url, i hope its very helpful to you.. https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753477/magento-multiple-stores-with-nginx

Comment: is it only language difference or there are some specific / unique products per store?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/162620)

Comment: @MagenX onlty the languages are different. No other changes.

Comment: @AnasMansuri Thank you for the suggestion. I've made several succesful rewrites, and I know how they work.

The main issue is, I think, that Magento does not pass the correct store view

I also tried:

location /ens/ {
fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE en;
rewrite /ens/(.*)?$ /en/$1 last;
try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$args;
}

But that refers also to the base store view and not the 'en' store view.

Comment: better option for you to keep it as is, just two websites with `MAGE_RUN_CODE` , with one language for your tagret group. keep it simple.

Comment: @MagenX but that does not solve my issue that I want to use /nl /en /de /fr and so on for multiple websites in one Magento 2 installation.

We need to use them all in the same backend.

Comment: there is no point to create separate store per language, if your product is absolutely the same for everyone

Comment: I don't have separate stores per language. I only have separate storeviews per language.

Comment: I had to give up. I was not able to solve this.